# Renewal of SSL certificate by ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I just want to know, ACM provides renewed SSL certificate to CloudFront or Elastic load balancer. Further, CloudFront delivers the renewed SSL certificate to client on request from client or just push the updated SSL certificate for established session.
Please reply.
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

From the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/managed-renewal.html)

> ACM provides managed renewal for your Amazon-issued SSL/TLS
>   certificates. This means that ACM tries to renew the certificates
>   before they expire. If possible, ACM renews your certificates
>   automatically with no action required from you.
>
> Note
>
> Automatic renewal is not available for either imported certificates or
>   for certificates associated with Route 53 private hosted zones. You
>   must renew these manually. For more information, see How Manual Domain
>   Validation Works .
>
> Note
>
> When ACM renews a certificate, the certificate's Amazon Resource Name
>   (ARN) remains the same. Also, ACM Certificates are regional resources.
>   If you have certificates for the same domain name in multiple AWS
>   Regions, ACM renews each of these certificates independently.
>
> Important
>
> Your ACM Certificate must be actively associated with a supported AWS
>   service before it can be automatically renewed. For information about
>   the resources that ACM supports, see Services Integrated with AWS
>   Certificate Manager.